# Quando abro o programa em Python diretamente no CMD, ele simplesmente fecha

Tags: python

Quando tento abrir este programa diretamente no CMD, sem abrir em CD caminho -> python arquivo.py, ele chega a abrir, mas ao dar enter, ele simplesmente fecha... Já gerei um executável também, através do cxFreeze, mas ao abrir e clicar o enter, ele fecha... Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import random
import numpy


nome = input("Insira seu nome: ")
nome_do_jogo = input("Digite o nome do jogo: ")
prim_num = input("Digite o primeiro numero que pode ser jogado: ")
ult_num = input("Digite o ultimo numero que pode ser jogado: ")
qtd_numeros = input("Digite a quantidade de numeros a serem gerados: ")
mega_sena = numpy.random.randint(int(prim_num), int(ult_num), (1, int(qtd_numeros)))
mega_sena.sort()


print(nome + ", na " + nome_do_jogo + ", você pode jogar os números: " + str(mega_sena))
```

Comment: tem como colocar um print do comando no cmd.
Testei colocando python arquivo.py e funfou

Comment: No CMD ele vai normal, mas, quando gero o executável, no primeiro enter ele fecha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a questão é que o programa abre o cmd *junto* com ele. Quando ele se encerra, o programa acaba, e o terminal onde ele estava rodando acaba junto.

A forma de resolver isso é incluir um `input()` em branco no final do programa. Ou pode ser `input("Pressione <enter> para encerrar!")` - o input suspende o programa até o usuário apertar enter, mesmo que não digite mais nada, e isso evita que o terminal feche.

Se o seu programa der algum erro antes de chegar nesse input final, pode ser que ele feche "instantaneamente" ainda - aí o melhor a fazer é abrir um cmd, mudar até a pasta do programa com o comando "cd" e executar o programa com "python .py" - aí, quando der erro, você vai ter a mensagem completa, que aponta a linha exata onde aconteceu o erro.

Você vai encontrar outras respostas, possivelmente nessa mesma pergunta, sugerindo o uso de `os.system('pause')` - isso funciona, mas pessoalmente eu considero bastante deselegante: a chamada `os.system` executa **um outro** programa além do seu, só pra esperar que uma tecla seja pressionada. Simplesmente chamar `input` resolve perfeitamente o problema.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou fazer um teste com input()!!
Abrindo como "python arquivo.py", ele vai até o final, mas, se eu abro diretamente o arquivo, o qual abre o cmd do python, ele fecha instantaneamente ao pressionar enter no ultimo input :/